# Laravel - View composer with controller method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

Is there a way to return the response of a controller method in a view composer function? This is currently returning a string, the namespace.

```
view()->composer('tasks.partial.tasksummary', function($view)
{
    $view->with('taskload', 'App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@taskLoad');
});
```

***or...*** would it be better to just inject the method in my partial directly (via `@inject('..')`)?

Comment: That sounds like something better suited for e.g. a task model. But you could probably do `$taskload = (new App\Http\Controllers\Taskcontroller)->taskLoad(); $view->with('taskload', $taskload);` or similar.

Comment: Decent solution. Not the prettiest, but it'll do the trick. Write an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's A solution but it's probably not THE solution. :) Thanks, I'll put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like something better suited for e.g. a task model. But you could do:

```
$taskload = (new App\Http\Controllers\Taskcontroller)->taskLoad(); 
$view->with('taskload', $taskload);
```

Comment: Nice. What other solution would you suggest?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your project or code. Generally, however, I treat composers and controllers as two ways of interacting between requests and logic. But I don't mix the two. So if I need some way of getting the data, I put it in a model, or in a repository, or in the database (etc.), depending on what it is exactly.

Comment: I hear you. Well, I put the logic in a controller initially...it's a fair bit of code generating the "taskload", uses a couple different models, etc. But then I needed this object on a handful of different pages throughout and didn't want to repeat the code a hundred times. So naturally, thought view composer. Maybe a repository/library is the best approach for this. Models, I tend to keep pretty clean. Just relations, scopes, attributes, etc.